# Creating a vector of size n based on an inputted matrix

Tags: matrix, vector, julia, lapack

So, I'm writing a function.  In order to begin the computation, I need to create a vector of 1s.  This is going to be multiplied by an inputted matrix A.

So if a matrix is 6x6, it becomes a vector of length 6, made up of 1s.  If it's 4x4, it becomes a vector of length 4 with all values at 1.

How do I make the vector the right size for any given matrix A?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the following matrix `A`:

```
julia> A=reshape(1:9,3,3)
3×3 reshape(::UnitRange{Int64}, 3, 3) with eltype Int64:
 1  4  7
 2  5  8
 3  6  9
```

Than you can do:

```
julia> A*ones(size(A,1))
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 12.0
 15.0
 18.0
```

(If you rather meant a horizontal vector of ones you could do `ones(1,size(A,1))*A`)

Note that the same effect can be simply achieved with the `dims` parameter of the `sum` function:

```
julia> sum(A,dims=2)
3×1 Matrix{Int64}:
 12
 15
 18
```

or if you want a `Vector`:

```
julia> vec(sum(A,dims=2))
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 12
 15
 18
```